# Adding points in Empty Polygon using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, symbology, point-in-polygon

I have a number of polygons on which I wish to make analysis using points data symbols.

Is there a method through which I may add points automatically within each polygon in separate locations?

For Example I found centroid (x,y), and used it as one location. I need 12 locations in one polygon where the polygons are not of regular shape and points may not overlap too.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want one point in each polygon? And it can be situated anywhere in that polygon (preferably center?)? And what is it that you want to automate?

Comment: @Martin I want 12 locations in each polygon. I calculated the centroid and used it as one location. In this way I did not have to mark all the points and with a single command each polygon had a point in its center. The points may be anywhere but within the polygon.

Answer (score 5):

If you have an Advanced (ArcInfo) license or a 3D or Spatial Analyst extension, you can use [Create Random Points](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000002r000000) with the following parameters:

[image]

Comment: This is a good option, however not available for v10.0.

Comment: Well yes it is, check the hyperlink.

Comment: I see now, my original search did not show that link.  Thanks for update!

Comment: License Issue!!! :( any other option...

Comment: Check this out: http://ianbroad.com/arcgis-toolbox-generate-random-points-arcpy/ (I've never tried and don't succeed to download it)

Comment: Easy, simple solution!

Comment: yes the download is not working GISGe